# Passing output of sh command and placing it in a placeholder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a code snippet like this

```sh
GCP_REGION="us-central1"
BUCKET_NAME="$(case $GCP_REGION in us*) echo "foo-bar-us";;asia*) echo "foo-bar-asia";;europe*) echo "foo-bar-eu";;*) echo "unknown GCP region";exit 1 ;; esac)";
```

Now instead of saving the output of `echo` to BUCKET_NAME, is there a way to pass it to next command `rclone mount gcs:$BUCKET_NAME /foo/bar`

Using `$BUCKET_NAME` in `rclone` is failing and using the DRY principle I was hoping to not use the `$BUCKET_NAME` at all.

Comment: You can put a command substitution anywhere, so you can write `rclone mount gcs:$(...) /foo/bar`

Comment: But if it's not working with the variable, it there's no reason why using the command substitution would work any better. Maybe you should figure out what's going wrong with the variable and fix that.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top of the script so you see how the variable is being substituted.

Comment: Remember to quote your variables: `"gcs:$BUCKET_NAME`. You need that if `$BUCKET_NAME` contains whitespace, like `unknown GCP region`

Comment: Note that the `exit 1` doesn't exit from the script, it just exits from the `$(...)` subshell.

Comment: Woah I'm a beginner and didn't know all these. Thanks a lot @Barmar. By quoting the variable for whitespace, should I do `"gcs:$BUCKET_NAME"` or `gcs:"$BUCKET_NAME"` ? and is there a way to exit from the outer shell too instead of just the subshell?

Comment: You can quote it either way.

Comment: The only way you can make it exit from the main script is if you enable `set -e` in the main script. Then any command that gets an error causes the script to exit.

Comment: You could also refactor it to a normal `case` statement instead of using a command substution. `CASE "$GCP_REGION" in us*) BUCKET_NAME=...;; asia*) BUCKET_NAME=...;; *) echo "Error"; exit 1;; esac`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```sh
case $GCP_REGION in us*) echo "foo-bar-us";;asia*) echo "foo-bar-asia";;europe*) echo "foo-bar-eu";;*) echo "unknown GCP region";exit 1 ;; esac | xargs -I '{}' rclone mount gcs:{} /foo/bar
```